# How to select folder path from listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview with folders. I am trying to get the files of a selected folder from the listview to add them to a listbox.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(listView1.SelectedItems);
    listBox1.Items.Add(filepath);
}
```

This is what I have and I know this should only add the folder to the listbox but it just adds (Collection) to the listbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Following @aria's code I switch `Path.GetDirectoryName(listview1.SelectedItems[i].Text)` to `Directory.GetFiles[i].Text)` but now it gives me an error.
`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path` and the path is to the debug folder of the project, not the actual folder path.

Why is it going to the debug folder instead?

Comment: `ListView.SelectedItems` returns a collection class, so I'm pretty sure your code will be failing when you try to pass the collection in to `Path.GetDirectoryName()`, which will be expecting a `string`

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work." is a very narrow problem description. You can really help the people who are willing to help you if you try to describe exactly what output you get, and/or what error messages you get

Comment: I am a little confused here. "selected folder from the listview" so your listview contains the folders?=! and you want to select one folder and then get all files in it and write the names into the `ListBox1` ? is that correct?

Comment: @MongZhu yes that's exactly what i am trying to do. sorry about my description, I'm still new to describing my code.

Comment: do you display the entire path of the directory in your listview? or simply the name ?

Comment: Just the name...I'm an idiot for not seeing that. EDIT: @MongZhu I changed my code for the listview and now the listbox is getting populated. Thank you for pointing it out for me.

Comment: you're welcome. glad to hear that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As their comments mentions `SelectedItems` will give you collection of `ListViewItem` so you can iterate over them like.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
  for(int i=0;i<=listView1.SelectedItems.Count-1;i++)
  {
      string filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text);
      listBox1.Items.Add(filepath);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing is getting added into the list box. No files or anything.

Comment: @MarcoAlba, What is the `Text` of `listView1.SelectedItems[i]` , for example it should be something like  `C:\Dir1\Dir2\\`

Comment: It should be `E:\Music\All Star\`

Comment: Okay, now I see what was wrong. I have two files in the folder. So now I added a `foreach (string adirs in filepath)` and it's giving me the error of `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path`

Comment: @MarcoAlba, then `GetDirectoryName` give you `E:\Music\`

Comment: Thank you, your code was correct. It was my listview's code that was incorrect. I changed my listview code and it's all working now.